# Find the kernel and range of the linear operator $Kf(x) = \int_0^1 \sin \pi (x-y) f(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is the following

> Find the kernel and range of the linear operator $K : C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ defined by
>   $$
> Kf(x) = \int_0^1 \sin (\pi (x-y)) f(y)dy
> $$

For the kernel, I tried to solve
$$
Kf(x) = \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \cos(\pi y)f(y)dy - \int_0^1\sin (\pi y) \cos(\pi x)f(y)dy = 0
$$
and I can't proceed further. And I have no idea how to find the range. Any hint or help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that you can pull $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\cos (\pi x)$ outside their respective integrals and that they're linearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $Kf''(x)+\pi^2Kf(x)=0$, which is a second order linear homogeneous differential equation, whose general solution is $Kf(x)=c_1\cos \pi x+c_2\sin \pi x$ so the range of $K$ is the two dimensional vector space spanned by $S=\{\cos \pi x,\sin\pi x\}.$

Now, using your idea and the fact that $\{\cos x,\sin x\}$ is linearly independent,

$f\in \ker\ K\Leftrightarrow \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \cos(\pi y)f(y)dy - \int_0^1\sin (\pi y) \cos(\pi x)f(y)dy =0\Leftrightarrow \left(\int_0^1 \cos(\pi y)f(y)dy\right)\sin (\pi x)+\left(\int_0^1 -\sin(\pi y)f(y)dy\right)\cos (\pi x)=0$

so $\int_0^1 \cos(\pi y)f(y)dy=\int_0^1 \sin(\pi y)f(y)dy=0\Rightarrow f\in S^{\perp}.$

Comment: I don't understand how you can solve this problem using only the second integral approach you used. I get that the range of the operator is a 2 dimensional subspace  of C([0,1]) spanned by sin and cos and from the linear independence of sin and cos we can say that both integrals vanish identically and that implies that function in the kernel has to be orthogonal to both sine and cos on [0,1].How do we reach the conclusion that there is no such function in C([0,1])?

Comment: That's what I said, the linear independence of sin and cos makes the integrals zero.What I don't understand Is how that implies ker K=0? I agree that there is no such vector (other than zero vector) that is mapped to zero(i.e orthogonal to sin and cos) in the 2d space spanned by cos and sin but the kernel is defined with reference to the domain, the vectors that in the domain that are mapped to zero. The domain C([0,1]) is much larger it is infinite dimensional How do we know that there is no such function in C([0,1]) that is orthogonal to both  sin and cos?